# How to correctly avoid "cast increases required alignment" warning when read(2)ing structs?

Tags: c, system-calls, memory-alignment

A lot of Linux kernel interfaces (inotify, etc.) work by `read(2)`ing data in the form of a struct from some file descriptor. The code to do so often goes something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

int main() {
        // all error checking omitted for brevity
        int inotify_fd = inotify_init();
        inotify_add_watch(inotify_fd, "file_to_watch", IN_ALL_EVENTS);
        char c[4096];
        for(;;) {
                ssize_t len = read(inotify_fd, c, sizeof(c));
                struct inotify_event *s;
                for(char* p = c; p < c + len; p += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + s->len) {
                        s = (struct inotify_event *)p;
                        // do stuff with s
                }
        }
}
```

When I compile the above with clang, I get this warning:

```
inotify.c:13:15: warning: cast from 'char *' to 'struct inotify_event *' increases required alignment from 1 to 4 [-Wcast-align]
                        s = (struct inotify_event *)p;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My first attempt to fix this warning was to fix the alignment: I tried using `#include <stdalign.h>` and `alignas(struct inotify_event)`, to no avail.

I'd like to actually fix this warning, not just silence it. How can I do so?

EDIT: Here's how read(2) on an inotify fd works, as documented by [its man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html):

> Each successful read(2) returns a buffer containing one or more of
>   the following structures:
>
> ```
>        struct inotify_event {
>            int      wd;       /* Watch descriptor */
>            uint32_t mask;     /* Mask describing event */
>            uint32_t cookie;   /* Unique cookie associating related
>                                  events (for rename(2)) */
>            uint32_t len;      /* Size of name field */
>            char     name[];   /* Optional null-terminated name */
>        };
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> This filename is null-terminated, and may include
>   further null bytes ('\0') to align subsequent reads to a suitable
>   address boundary.
>
> The len field counts all of the bytes in name, including the null
>   bytes; the length of each inotify_event structure is thus
>   sizeof(struct inotify_event)+len.
>
> The behavior when the buffer given to read(2) is too small to return
>   information about the next event depends on the kernel version: in
>   kernels before 2.6.21, read(2) returns 0; since kernel 2.6.21, read(2)
>   fails with the error EINVAL.  Specifying a buffer of size
>
> ```
> sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1
> ```
>
> will be sufficient to read at least one event.

I can't read partial structs, such as reading the name separately from the fixed-size piece. If I don't specify a big enough buffer to read an entire struct, I don't get any of it.

Comment: "How can I do so" really depends on how it is written to get it all right, not just only fix the alignment issue.  Recommend to post how the data is written.

Comment: The data isn't really "written" at all. In the real code, instead of reading from stdin (fd 0), I'm reading from one of the special file descriptors I mentioned, where calling read() just makes the kernel copy the appropriate data into buf, without any corresponding write() ever having happened.

Comment: The special file descriptor would be expected to document layout.  As able, post/link that info relating to your special file descriptor.  Or just use the `union` trick.

Comment: @chux inotify is one such special FD. I edited the requested info into the question.

Comment: Use [union idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52350117/2410359) expect `char    buf[1];` --> `char    buf[4096];`.  As part of robust error checking insure return value from `read()` makes sense with `s->len`.

Comment: @chux the union idea lets me get a pointer to the first struct in the buffer without a warning, but doesn't seem to work for the subsequent ones. I just put a full example with inotify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
union {
     char    buf[1];
     struct some_struct mine;
} b;
```

Ensures that b.buf and b.mine have the same address; furthermore, any required alignment is guaranteed by the compiler.   There is almost never a need for the attribute extensions (eg. alignas), and a lot of value in having source free of that crud.

Comment: And how should code then call `read()`?  Note OP's  `sizeof(c)` argument.